# Find the volume of the solid V given by $x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 1$ and $x \geq 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Why is theta bounded by $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$? Can't it be bounded by $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$??

Comment: You can use $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to do the integral but you will have to multiply the result by $2$. This is because you are calculating the volume of a parabolic dome sliced in half down the middle. The integral will still work even if you use $0$ and $\pi$ because of the symmetry of the volume but then $x$ won't be positive.

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm quite bad at visualizing 3D graphs :/ Are there any other ways to determine the bounds for theta?